# Creating columns of a table using the rows of another

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, pivot-table

I'm working on my project in php [handling students attendance system]. I have a list of students along with their unique id[`jntuno`] and I need to create a database in mysql for storing the daily attendance of each student for each subject. So I created my tables in this way :

I have a table `students` in mysql with the following fields and data in it :

[image: my table contents]

now I want to create a new table with the each of the values in the `jntuno` field as a columns of my new table.

I want my new table [let us name it `attendance`] to have columns like this :

```
+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|11341A0501  |11341A0502 |11341A0503|11341A0504 |11341A0505 |......      
+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|            |           |          |           |           |
```

**How to do this in mysql ?**

I will later add 3  fields to the `attendance` table namely  :

->  `date`[the date on which a particular subject is taught] ,

->`subject`[the name of the subject taught] and

->`hours taught`[the number of hours for which a particular subject is taught(can be 1 or 2 or 3 ... upto 6)]

every `subject` taught on a particular `date` will be adding a new `row` to the `attendance` table

**Example:**

```
+------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|date        |subject    | classes taught  |11341A0501  |11341A0502 |11341A0503|11341A0504 |11341A0505 |..    
+------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|2013-09-31  |OOPS       |3                |2           |3          |0         |1          |3          |
```

I choose the tables in this way so that the entry of attendance into the table would be more faster.

But many call this a **BAD DATABASE STRUCTURE** . So  please suggest me if there's some other good and efficient database design for my problem

Comment: This is usually not a well-designed model. Are you sure to have a normalized database schema?

Comment: is there an alternative for this type of problem ? if so please suggest me

Comment: If you want to store data about students, simply add a `student_id` in your new table. Define it as a *foreign key* to your `student` table. Maybe [this](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html) could help you.

Comment: You can do this by using alter table for the new table when any new entry is get inserted in your previous table.

Comment: Not how, tell us why you want student_id as column names, If your table grows to 5K student id, then will you create table 5k rows? bad design.

Comment: that's not gonna happen @mr_eclair because there will be only 100 students at max per a classroom in the college. So the same type of tables will be created for each and every classroom present in the college

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the new table with the following statements:

```
select @s:=concat('create table students_col (',group_concat(jntunno,' CHAR(10)' order by slno),')') from students;
prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

observe how the `CREATE TABLE` is constructed using the `group_concat`

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/872b1/1)

In case you also want to insert the names, this is the statement to it:

```
select @s:=concat('insert into students_col values (',group_concat(concat('"',name,'"') order by slno),')') from students;
prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
select * from students_col;
```

Here is my whole trail:

```
mysql> drop table if exists students;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table students (slno integer, jntunno char(10), name varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into students values (1,'1134A0501','ADARI GOPI');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into students values (2,'1134A0502','BALU');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into students values (3,'1134A0503','GEETHA');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table if exists students_col;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @s:=concat('create table students_col (',group_concat(jntunno,' CHAR(10)' order by slno),')') from students;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @s:=concat('create table students_col (',group_concat(jntunno,' CHAR(10)' order by slno),')') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| create table students_col (1134A0501 CHAR(10),1134A0502 CHAR(10),1134A0503 CHAR(10))          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

mysql> deallocate prepare stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select @s:=concat('insert into students_col values (',group_concat(concat('"',name,'"') order by slno),')') from students;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @s:=concat('insert into students_col values (',group_concat(concat('"',name,'"') order by slno),')') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| insert into students_col values ("ADARI GOPI","BALU","GEETHA")                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> deallocate prepare stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select * from students_col;
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1134A0501  | 1134A0502 | 1134A0503 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ADARI GOPI | BALU      | GEETHA    |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: that was awesome ! .... can you also suggest me some better database design for this type of case please !

Comment: I wondered why you need the that many columns. I would suggest you something if I would know what you actually intend to do. Honestly, I would not create a table like this. Let's say you want to populate an HTML table like this then I would rather read the existing table and construct the HTML output from it in for example PHP or some other server sided language.

Comment: please check my question again @hol . i have updated the description

Comment: Don't make a table with that many columns, just two tables and join them. If you don't know how to do that, try to read some basic literature about databases and when you go stuck create a **new** questions. When you then need to show the PHP page with columns for each student and you do not know how to do that, well again, learn some basics and if you cannot figure it out, then create a **new** question. Do not expect to get answers on an edited and edited question. I speak for myself but maybe others feel the same, it is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

This procedure will do the work:

```
DELIMITER ||
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`pivot`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`pivot`()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`new_table`;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`jntunno`, ' CHAR(10) NOT NULL') SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `test`.`students` INTO @sql;
    SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (', @sql, ') ENGINE=InnoDB;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    SET @sql := NULL;
END;
||
DELIMITER ;
```

If you cannot use stored procedures, you can easily translate that code into PHP, or any language you use.

Comment: that was awesome ! .... can you also suggest me some better database design for this type of case please !

Comment: The design you wanted to use could be good or horrible, it depends from what you need to do. Databases should be designed to quicky answer your queries. So I (or anyone) really need to know something about your queries, before suggesting a design

Answer (score 0):

```
create table new_table
select distinct jntuno from students;
```

or

```
create table new_table (jntuno varchar(10));
insert into new_table 
select distinct jntuno from students;
```

Comment: the solution you gave creates a new table with `jntuno` as a column in it and imports all the values of that field from `students` table... that's not what i wanted !... i want each of the row value to be a column of my new table

Comment: I see. Don't do that. That is really bad DB design.

Comment: is there an alternative for this type of problem ?

Comment: I don't know. You did not describe your problem actually.

Comment: yeah... it would be too long to describe my problem here ... i'll make out a new question regarding the choice of tables and columns ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
create table new_table (jntuno varchar(10),fieldsname varchar(10));
insert into new_table(jntuno,fieldsname)
values(select distinct jntuno from s tudents,'test');
```

Comment: I see. Don't do that. That is really bad DB design

Comment: "Not relational" does not mean "bad design". It depends from what he needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try an answer your question of how to better design this DB:

The Explanation:
Instead of having a column for each student and I assume a row for each day, you should set the table up to have a row for each student x by each day and you can use foreign keys to enforce data integrity

The main reason for this is generally something like the number of students is not a static number. In order to optimize your data usage in a setup like this you would essentially need to recreate the table every time a student is added or removed.
So if you start out with 30 students you then have a table with 30 columns, if then the number of students drops to 15 every time you add a record you are creating 15 unused values and this will gradually take up a lot more storage than you actually need.

Solution:
If you structure your attendance table like this:

```
attendance ID | JNTUNO | Date | Subject | Hours
```

Attendance id will simply be a unique identifier for the row, I would suggest either a guid or an auto incremented int

JNTUNO would be a foreign key, pointing back to your Student table

This way on the scenario I presented earlier, with 30 students you will add 30 rows every day with 5 values each but when your number of students changes to 15 you add only 15 rows.

I don't know MYSQL syntax very well but if you'd like I can try to piece together a concrete implementation if my explanation isn't clear; just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s as varchar(8000);
declare @s2 as varchar(25);
 set @s ='create table attendance (';
 declare s1  cursor
 for 
 select jntunno from students  
 OPEN s1 
    fetch next from s1 into @s2 
    set @s = @s +'['+@s2 +'] numeric(4,2)'
    fetch next from s1 into @s2
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
         set @s = @s +',['+@s2 +'] numeric(4,2)'
         fetch next from s1 into @s2
     end
 CLOSE s1 -- close the cursor
DEALLOCATE s1
set @s = @s+')'
exec(@s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be adding columns every time you add a student.

I'd design it like this:

```
Table:  Attendance
    Columns:
        Date
        Subject
        ClassNumber
        Missed_jntuno
```

Then you add a row for each student/class combo that is missed (or, if students miss more than they attend, you might want to flip that to a `Attended_jntuno` field instead and add the row when they make it to class — or if you're really feeling completest, always write a row for every student and then have another bit/boolean column for attended or not).

One advantage to this way is that you can see which classes got which students in addition to a daily sum.  Another is that this is much friendlier to things like OLAP cubes for flexible reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Basic database design is jumping up right now and shouting in your face: "You're doing it wrong!".

What you're trying to do here is put a many to many relationship in 1 table, while it should actually be in 3 tables.

What you should do is keep your student table as-is and add a `subjects` table with 1 row for each subject, but not including the date.

Then you want to have another table `Attendance` with a reference column to Student ID, a reference column to subject ID, a Date field and a Presence field.

What you're trying to do right now is trying to store what's basically volatile data in your metadata about your table, which you should never do. For example, what if you have a student join your school 1 week into the grade? then your table suddenly gets an extra column with no values for the first week.

In addition, your system means that database queries are much harder, since you're storing data you want to filter on in your column header. Other people in here have given a number of reasons why this is a bad idea.